# C# chess engine performance

Tags: c#, performance, chess

I am creating my own bitboard chess engine in C#. I am trying to optimize my make move, unmake move, and move generating functions to get a good fast base. My C# skills are average and got some tips from articles, forums and videos on how to increase performance.

If you have any advice on how I can make it faster then I would appreciate any advice highly. These functions are run millions of times due to the nature of negamax algorithm so any millisecond that can be saved will result in great increase overall.

Sorry if this is not how you do it here, and please let me know if you need any more information. The relevant code with variable declarations can be found below.

```
    public ulong[][] pieces;
    public ulong[] occupancy;
    public ulong occupancyAll;
    public ulong enPassant;
    public ulong castling;
    public int colorToMove;
    public int movesCount;
    public int halfMoveClock;
    public int nullMoves;

    public int[] PSTValuesOpening;
    public int[] PSTValuesEnding;

    public int currentGamePhase;

    public List<int> capturedPieces;
    public List<int> promotedPieces;
    public List<ulong> castlings;
    public List<ulong> zobristKeys;
    public List<ulong> enPassants;
    public List<int> halfMoveClockList;

    public ulong zobristKey;

    public Move[] possibleMoves;
    public int movesAdded;

    public string stalemateReason;

    public int[] kingPositions;

    public BoardState()
    {
        // Init bitboards
        pieces = new ulong[2][];
        pieces[Color.White] = new ulong[6];
        pieces[Color.Black] = new ulong[6];
        occupancy = new ulong[2];

        // Init lists
        PSTValuesOpening = new int[2];
        PSTValuesEnding = new int[2];

        capturedPieces = new List<int>();
        promotedPieces = new List<int>();
        castlings = new List<ulong>();
        zobristKeys = new List<ulong>();
        enPassants = new List<ulong>();
        halfMoveClockList = new List<int>();

        // Init other variables
        currentGamePhase = 0;

        kingPositions = new int[2];
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ###################################################################################
    //                                GENERATE MOVES
    // ###################################################################################
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Move[] GetAllMoves()
    {
        // Clear list of moves
        possibleMoves = new Move[GameConstants.maxMovesInAPosition];
        movesAdded = 0;

        GetQuietMoves(false);
        GetCaptureMoves(false);

        return possibleMoves;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private void AddAllTargetSquares(byte fromSquare, ulong targets, byte piece, MoveFlags flag)
    {
        for (; targets != 0; targets = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(targets))
        {
            AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(targets), piece, (byte)flag);
        }
    }

    public Move[] GetQuietMoves(bool justQuiets)
    {
        // Clear list of moves if we should just get the quiet moves
        if (justQuiets)
        {
            possibleMoves = new Move[GameConstants.maxMovesInAPosition];
            movesAdded = 0;
        }

        // ##############################################################
        // --------------  Go through all pieces ------------------------
        // ##############################################################
        byte fromSquare;

        // Pawns
        int direction = colorToMove == Color.White ? -8 : 8;
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Pawn]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);

            // Check that square is empty in front of pawn
            if ((Pawns.QuietMasksOneStep[colorToMove][fromSquare] & occupancyAll) == 0)
            {
                // One step moves
                // Check if from square is on a promoting row
                if ((GameConstants.fromPromotionRows[colorToMove] & (1ul << fromSquare)) != 0)
                {
                    AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + direction), Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.PromotionKnight);
                    AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + direction), Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.PromotionBishop);
                    AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + direction), Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.PromotionRook);
                    AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + direction), Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.PromotionQueen);
                }
                // Else a normal one step move
                else
                {
                    AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + direction), Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.Quiet);
                }

                // Two step moves, if pawn is on start row and no pawns on end square
                if ((GameConstants.pawnStartRow[colorToMove] & (1ul << fromSquare)) != 0)
                {                        
                    if ((Pawns.QuietMasksTwoStep[colorToMove][fromSquare] & occupancyAll) == 0)
                    {
                        AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + 2 * direction), Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.DoublePawnPush);
                    }
                }
            }               
        }

        // Knights
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Knight]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Knights.AttackMasks[fromSquare] & ~occupancyAll, Piece.Knight, MoveFlags.Quiet);
        }

        // Bishops
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Bishop]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Bishops.GetAttacks(fromSquare, occupancyAll) & ~occupancyAll, Piece.Bishop, MoveFlags.Quiet);
        }

        // Rooks
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Rook]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Rooks.GetAttacks(fromSquare, occupancyAll) & ~occupancyAll, Piece.Rook, MoveFlags.Quiet);
        }

        // Queens
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Queen]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Queens.GetAttacks(fromSquare, occupancyAll) & ~occupancyAll, Piece.Queen, MoveFlags.Quiet);
        }

        // Kings
        fromSquare = (byte)kingPositions[colorToMove];
        AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Kings.AttackMasks[fromSquare] & ~occupancyAll, Piece.King, MoveFlags.Quiet);

        // Castling
        // White side
        if (colorToMove == Color.White)
        {
            // King side
            if (Kings.WhiteCanCastleKingSide(this, colorToMove))
            {
                AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + 2), Piece.King, (byte)MoveFlags.Castle);
            }
            // Queen side
            if (Kings.WhiteCanCastleQueenSide(this, colorToMove))
            {
                AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare - 2), Piece.King, (byte)MoveFlags.Castle);
            }
        }
        // Black side
        else
        {
            // King side
            if (Kings.BlackCanCastleKingSide(this, colorToMove))
            {
                AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare + 2), Piece.King, (byte)MoveFlags.Castle);
            }
            // Queen side
            if (Kings.BlackCanCastleQueenSide(this, colorToMove))
            {
                AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, (byte)(fromSquare - 2), Piece.King, (byte)MoveFlags.Castle);
            }
        }

        return possibleMoves;
    }

    public Move[] GetCaptureMoves(bool justCaptures)
    {
        // Clear list of moves if we should just get capturing moves
        if (justCaptures)
        {
            possibleMoves = new Move[GameConstants.maxMovesInAPosition];
            movesAdded = 0;
        }

        // ##############################################################
        // --------------  Go through all pieces ------------------------
        // ##############################################################
        byte fromSquare;

        // Pawns
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Pawn]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            ulong targets = Pawns.AttackMasks[colorToMove][fromSquare] & occupancy[Color.Invert(colorToMove)];

            // Check for promotions
            if ((GameConstants.fromPromotionRows[colorToMove] & (1ul << fromSquare)) != 0)
            {
                AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, targets, Piece.Pawn, MoveFlags.PromotionKnightCapture);
                AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, targets, Piece.Pawn, MoveFlags.PromotionBishopCapture);
                AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, targets, Piece.Pawn, MoveFlags.PromotionRookCapture);
                AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, targets, Piece.Pawn, MoveFlags.PromotionQueenCapture);
            }
            else
            {
                AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, targets, Piece.Pawn, MoveFlags.Capture);
            }

            // Enpassant
            if (enPassant != 0)
            {
                ulong epAttacks = Pawns.AttackMasks[colorToMove][fromSquare] & enPassant;
                if (epAttacks != 0)
                {
                    byte toSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(epAttacks);
                    AddMoveToPossibleMoves(fromSquare, toSquare, Piece.Pawn, (byte)MoveFlags.EnPassant);
                }
            }
        }

        // Knights
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Knight]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Knights.AttackMasks[fromSquare] & occupancy[Color.Invert(colorToMove)], Piece.Knight, MoveFlags.Capture);
        }

        // Bishops
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Bishop]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Bishops.GetAttacks(fromSquare, occupancyAll) & occupancy[Color.Invert(colorToMove)], Piece.Bishop, MoveFlags.Capture);
        }

        // Rooks
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Rook]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Rooks.GetAttacks(fromSquare, occupancyAll) & occupancy[Color.Invert(colorToMove)], Piece.Rook, MoveFlags.Capture);
        }

        // Queens
        for (ulong pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Queen]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
        {
            fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);
            AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Queens.GetAttacks(fromSquare, occupancyAll) & occupancy[Color.Invert(colorToMove)], Piece.Queen, MoveFlags.Capture);
        }

        // Kings
        fromSquare = (byte)kingPositions[colorToMove];
        AddAllTargetSquares(fromSquare, Kings.AttackMasks[fromSquare] & occupancy[Color.Invert(colorToMove)], Piece.King, MoveFlags.Capture);

        return possibleMoves;
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ###################################################################################
    //                            MAKE AND UNMAKE MOVES
    // ###################################################################################
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public bool MakeMove(Move move)
    {
        // Increase counters
        if (colorToMove == Color.White) movesCount++;

        // Add variables that can't be tracked in any other way to lists
        castlings.Add(castling);
        zobristKeys.Add(zobristKey);
        enPassants.Add(enPassant);
        halfMoveClockList.Add(halfMoveClock);

        // Update king position
        if (move.pieceMoved == Piece.King)
        {
            kingPositions[colorToMove] = move.toSquare;
        }

        // Increase halfmove clock, resets to 0 further down if applicable
        halfMoveClock++;

        // Check if enpassant is possible and if so disable it
        if (enPassant != 0)
        {
            int enPassantRank = GeneralBitOperations.BitScan(enPassant) % 8;
            zobristKey = Zobrist.ToggleEnPassant(zobristKey, enPassantRank);
            enPassant = 0;
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------
        //            Check for different move types
        // ------------------------------------------------------

        // Quiet moves that are not double pushes
        if (MoveFunctions.IsQuiet(move.flag))
        {
            MovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.MovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);

            // Reset halfmove clock if pawn move
            if (move.pieceMoved == Piece.Pawn) halfMoveClock = 0;

        }
        // Double pawn pushes
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsDoublePawnPush(move.flag))
        {
            // Reset halfmove clock
            halfMoveClock = 0;

            // Move piece
            MovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.MovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);

            // Enable enpassant
            ulong epSquare = colorToMove == Color.White ? 1ul << move.toSquare + 8 : 1ul << move.toSquare - 8;
            enPassant |= epSquare;
            zobristKey = Zobrist.ToggleEnPassant(zobristKey, GeneralBitOperations.BitScan(epSquare) % 8);

        }
        // Enpassant moves
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsEnPassant(move.flag))
        {
            // Find enemy pawn (which is not on the toSquare)
            int enemyPieceSquare = colorToMove == Color.White ? move.toSquare + 8 : move.toSquare - 8;
            int capturedPiece = Piece.Pawn;
            capturedPieces.Add(capturedPiece);

            // Move own pawn and remove enemy pawn
            MovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.MovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            RemovePiece(Color.Invert(colorToMove), capturedPiece, enemyPieceSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemovePiece(zobristKey, Color.Invert(colorToMove), capturedPiece, enemyPieceSquare);
        }
        // Capture moves
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsCapture(move.flag))
        {
            // Reset halfmove clock
            halfMoveClock = 0;

            // Remove captured piece from its square and add it to list of captured pieces
            int capturedPiece = MoveFunctions.GetCapturedPiece(pieces[Color.Invert(colorToMove)], move.toSquare);
            RemovePiece(Color.Invert(colorToMove), capturedPiece, move.toSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemovePiece(zobristKey, Color.Invert(colorToMove), capturedPiece, move.toSquare);
            capturedPieces.Add(capturedPiece);

            // Check for promotion captures and if so move in special way
            if (MoveFunctions.IsPromotion(move.flag))
            {
                // Find the piece that we should promote to
                int promotionPiece = GetPromotionPiece(move.flag);

                // Remove pawn from square and add the promoted piece instead
                RemovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare);
                zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare);
                AddPiece(colorToMove, promotionPiece, move.toSquare);
                zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, promotionPiece, move.toSquare);

                // Add to list of promoted pieces
                promotedPieces.Add(promotionPiece);
            }
            // If not it is a normal capture
            else
            {
                // Move the piece as normal
                MovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
                zobristKey = Zobrist.MovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            }
        }
        // Castling moves
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsCastling(move.flag))
        {
            // Reset halfmove clock
            halfMoveClock = 0;

            // Get from and to square for the rook
            int rookFromSquare = GameConstants.rookCastling[move.toSquare][0];
            int rookToSquare = GameConstants.rookCastling[move.toSquare][1];

            // Move rook and king to the correct places
            MovePiece(colorToMove, Piece.King, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            MovePiece(colorToMove, Piece.Rook, rookFromSquare, rookToSquare);

            zobristKey = Zobrist.MovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, Piece.King, move.fromSquare, move.toSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.MovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, Piece.Rook, rookFromSquare, rookToSquare);

        }
        // Normal promotion moves that are not captures
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsPromotion(move.flag))
        {
            // Get what piece was promoted
            int promotionPiece = GetPromotionPiece(move.flag);

            // Remove pawn from square and add promoted piece on toSquare
            RemovePiece(colorToMove, Piece.Pawn, move.fromSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.fromSquare);
            AddPiece(colorToMove, promotionPiece, move.toSquare);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemovePiece(zobristKey, colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.toSquare);

            // Add piece to list
            promotedPieces.Add(promotionPiece);
        }

        // If castling rights, check and remove the correct ones
        if (castling != 0)
        {
            ulong updateMask = GameConstants.updateCastlingRights[move.fromSquare] & GameConstants.updateCastlingRights[move.toSquare];
            castling &= updateMask;
            zobristKey = Zobrist.AddOrRemoveCastlingRights(zobristKey, updateMask);
        }

        // Check if move is legal (king is not under attack after move is done)
        if (!IsSquareAttacked(colorToMove, kingPositions[colorToMove]))
        {
            // Change turns
            colorToMove = Color.Invert(colorToMove);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.ChangeSide(zobristKey);

            return true;
        }
        // If not, then unmake the move and return false
        else
        {
            // Change turns
            colorToMove = Color.Invert(colorToMove);
            zobristKey = Zobrist.ChangeSide(zobristKey);

            UnmakeMove(move);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void UnmakeMove(Move move)
    {
        // Change turn
        colorToMove = Color.Invert(colorToMove);

        // Update king position
        if (move.pieceMoved == Piece.King)
        {
            kingPositions[colorToMove] = move.fromSquare;
        }

        // Cache last indices
        int lastIndexCaptured = capturedPieces.Count - 1;
        int lastIndexPromoted = promotedPieces.Count - 1;
        int lastIndexHalfMoveClock = halfMoveClockList.Count - 1;
        int lastIndexZobristKeys = zobristKeys.Count - 1;
        int lastIndexCastlings = castlings.Count - 1;
        int lastIndexEnPassants = enPassants.Count - 1;

        // Handle different move types
        if (MoveFunctions.IsQuiet(move.flag) || MoveFunctions.IsDoublePawnPush(move.flag))
        {
            MovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.toSquare, move.fromSquare);
        }
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsEnPassant(move.flag))
        {
            int enemyColor = Color.Invert(colorToMove);
            int enemyPieceField = colorToMove == Color.White ? (move.toSquare + 8) : (move.toSquare - 8);
            int capturedPiece = capturedPieces[lastIndexCaptured];

            MovePiece(colorToMove, Piece.Pawn, move.toSquare, move.fromSquare);
            AddPiece(Color.Invert(colorToMove), capturedPiece, enemyPieceField);

            // Remove last captured piece directly
            capturedPieces.RemoveAt(lastIndexCaptured);
        }
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsCapture(move.flag))
        {
            int enemyColor = Color.Invert(colorToMove);
            int capturedPiece = capturedPieces[lastIndexCaptured];

            // Capturing promotion
            if (MoveFunctions.IsPromotion(move.flag))
            {
                int promotedPiece = promotedPieces[lastIndexPromoted];
                promotedPieces.RemoveAt(lastIndexPromoted);
                RemovePiece(colorToMove, promotedPiece, move.toSquare);
                AddPiece(colorToMove, Piece.Pawn, move.fromSquare);
            }
            else
            {
                MovePiece(colorToMove, move.pieceMoved, move.toSquare, move.fromSquare);
            }

            AddPiece(enemyColor, capturedPiece, move.toSquare);

            // Remove last captured piece directly
            capturedPieces.RemoveAt(lastIndexCaptured);
        }
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsCastling(move.flag))
        {
            // Get from and to square for the rook
            int rookFromSquare = GameConstants.rookCastling[move.toSquare][0];
            int rookToSquare = GameConstants.rookCastling[move.toSquare][1];

            // Move rook and king to the correct places
            MovePiece(colorToMove, Piece.King, move.toSquare, move.fromSquare);
            MovePiece(colorToMove, Piece.Rook, rookToSquare, rookFromSquare);
        }
        else if (MoveFunctions.IsPromotion(move.flag))
        {
            int promotedPiece = promotedPieces[lastIndexPromoted];
            promotedPieces.RemoveAt(lastIndexPromoted);
            RemovePiece(colorToMove, promotedPiece, move.toSquare);
            AddPiece(colorToMove, Piece.Pawn, move.fromSquare);
        }

        // Update with latest move variables
        halfMoveClock = halfMoveClockList[lastIndexHalfMoveClock];
        zobristKey = zobristKeys[lastIndexZobristKeys];
        castling = castlings[lastIndexCastlings];
        enPassant = enPassants[lastIndexEnPassants];

        // Remove from lists directly
        halfMoveClockList.RemoveAt(lastIndexHalfMoveClock);
        zobristKeys.RemoveAt(lastIndexZobristKeys);
        castlings.RemoveAt(lastIndexCastlings);
        enPassants.RemoveAt(lastIndexEnPassants);

        // Decrease moves count if white to move
        if (colorToMove == Color.White) movesCount--;
    }
```

Comment: `how [one does] it here` there is guidance: [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/93149)

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, I *highly* recommend these two videos from Sebastian Lague: https://youtu.be/U4ogK0MIzqk?si=N4r0-DtGTRlXAW9I and https://youtu.be/_vqlIPDR2TU?si=hbNTIit5Y60_FX4a.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I can give you a few performance tips.

1. Benchmark everything (https://benchmarkdotnet.org/).

   It is impossible to optimise code without metrics on how the changes you are making have impact performance. This will also help you identify bottlenecks

   With that in mind I see you have enabled aggressive inlining for one of your methods. Did you test that this made the code faster? Because sometimes aggressive inlining hurts performance and a lot of the time the JIT will inline methods for you.
2. Clean up the code

   It is very hard to identify performance optimisations in messy code. It can be very hard to do this if you don't know where to start but your pawn `for` loop in `GetQuietMoves` could look something like this:

   ```
    for (var pieceBB = pieces[colorToMove][Piece.Pawn]; pieceBB != 0; pieceBB = GeneralBitOperations.PopLSB(pieceBB))
    {
          fromSquare = (byte)GeneralBitOperations.GetLSBIndex(pieceBB);

          if (!Pawns.CanMove(colorToMove, fromSquare, occupancyAll)) break;

          var isPromotingRow = IsPromotingRow(GameConstants.fromPromotionRows[colorToMove], fromSquare)

          PossibleMoves.Add(fromSquare,
               fromSquare + direction,
               Piece.Pawn, 
               isPromotingRow
               ? MoveFlags.Promotion
               : MoveFlags.Quiet);

           if ((Pawns.CanMoveTwoSteps(colorToMove, fromSquare, occupancyAll))
           {
               PossibleMoves.Add(fromSquare,
               fromSquare + 2 * direction, 
               Piece.Pawn, 
               MoveFlags.DoublePawnPush);
           }

   }
   ```

   This is not to say the code above is finished or even possible to attain with your current design but it is easier to understand and will be easier to diagnose performance issues.
3. Try to solve problems once.

   It seems like in your code you account for which colour it is to move in every method. Things like this can lead to code acrobatics which can hurt performance. Maybe a design that is indifferent to which colour it is to move? This will also help you to clean up a lot of the methods and reduce mental strain when coding, because now you have one less thing to think about.

   So I would start by "cleaning up" your code in whatever way you can. Then measure the performance of your methods with benchmark dotnet. Only then you can start thinking about more specialised optimisations.

   Some optimisations to think about: Branchless code, SIMD, Parallel computing, Bit hacking, Use of correct data structures (the chessboard can be seen as a matrix or maybe it could be viewed as a graph?), minimising heap allocation (think `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>`), loop unrolling, faster array access and looping (take a look at the `MemoryMarshal` class and the `Unsafe` library).

   Then you can even combine these all together for example the Vector libraries provided by .NET have methods like `ShiftLeft` and `LoadUnsafe`.

Anyway apologies I can't give examples of applying these techniques to your code. I think you have more low-hanging fruit to deal with first before considering more advanced optimisations.

Hope that helps :)